# Why does this nested SVG not work in Firefox?

Tags: svg, firefox

I'm creating a contact sheet that displays all the icons in a library. I've built it using nested SVGs. Here's a minimal version:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <svg id="sheet_core" width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0">
        <svg width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0">
            <symbol id="piece" viewBox="-2.5 -2.5 105 105">
                <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" data-playerfill="true" fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000"></circle>
            </symbol>
            <use href="#piece" x="25" y="25" transform="matrix(0.75,0,0,0.75,6.25,6.25)"></use>
            <text x="0" y="192.1015625" svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}">piece</text>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Opera, but does *not* work in Firefox.

You should see this: https://ibb.co/VT8SSSd.

But in Firefox, I get this: https://ibb.co/5L7PP22.

If I inspect the code, the `<symbol>`s are greyed out, suggesting they are not being referenced, when they very clearly are right afterwards. I also tried moving all the symbols into a global `<defs>`, but that didn't work either. Any ideas how to tweak this so it will work in Firefox too?

These SVG browser differences are maddening, I've got to say.

Comment: The snippet looks the same in Chrome and Firefox to me. What difference am I supposed to be seeing?

Comment: Nested SVG's tend to have undiscovered bugs.

Comment: Edited to add pictures of what I'm seeing and not seeing.

Comment: Are you reusing the id value i.e. are your id values duplicated somehow?

Comment: Nope, and they're certainly not in this minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Once I loaded the SVG on my website so I could test in some different environments, it suddenly started working. My suspicion is there's some weird CSPF happening, perhaps only on my end. But the SVG does not appear to be the fundamental problem.

As you were.